# A Taylor series given by an integral: how to compute the radius of convergence?

Tags: calculus

I have to compute the radius of convergence for the Taylor series of $f(x)$ around $x=0$, where $$ f(x)=\int_0^1 \log\left(x+\sqrt{t^2+1}\right)dt.$$
Any hints?

Comment: The Taylor series around $x=0$ converges up to a radius where the nearest singularity of the function occurs.  In some problems there is a singularity in the complex plane closer than the one on the real axis, but at a glance that is not the difficulty here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is an analytic function in a neighbourhood of $x=0$, the radius of convergence of $f(x)$ and $f'(x)$ are the same. Now notice that, by differentiation under the integral sign:

$$ f'(x) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{x+\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n x^n}{\sqrt{1+t^2}^{n+1}}\,dt $$
hence:

$$ \left|[x^n]\,f'(x)\right| = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+t^2}^{n+1}}= \int_{0}^{\pi/4}\cos(\theta)^{n-1}\,d\theta.$$
Very few (at most $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}^{n}}$) is lost when approximating the last integral with:
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)^{n-1}\,d\theta = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{2\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}\approx\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}$$
and that gives that the radius of convergence is just $\color{red}{1}$.

Comment: what did you do in line 1, after differentiating with respect to x? How did you get that sum?

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz: I expanded the ratio as a geometric series.